# Database Schema for Parent-Child Relationships

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I need to develop a database schema for a pediatrics database that allows the following:

1. Store last name, first name, date of birth, and gender for each patient.
2. Store all applicable guardians that may include mother, father, legal guardian and their relationship to the patient (child).
3. Identifies patient siblings and their relationship to the patient.

4,  Allows for patients to become guardians/parents over time.

5. Stores phones numbers linked to each individual including patients and parents/guardians.

I'm really locked up on the best way to tackle this problem.  I'm considering three tables, tblPatients, tblGuardians, and tblTelephones, but I think this would require multiple entries for parents who have multiple children.  I'm sure this problem has been solved in the past, but I haven't found a suitable answer.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: You're after many to many relationships.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 4. Allows for patients to become guardians/parents over time.

This is key.  If patients may become guardians/parents later, you should probably have a table for "person" that describes any kind of person, and then categorize that person with other tables.

For example

- `PERSON` table defines demographics, (last name, first name, date of
  birth, and gender, phone number etc)
- `PATIENT` Table defines patient data with FK, and points to
  a specific PERSON, optionally with a unique constraint on
  `PATIENT.PERSONID` to ensure that no two patients are the same
  person.  Presence of a record in this table implies a `PERSON` is a `PATIENT`
- `RELATIONSHIP` table links two `PERSON` records together and defines a relationship.  `Person1ID`, `Person2ID`, and `RelationshipType` for example.

Comment: Thank you for the response and help.  Its along the lines of what I was thinking, but let me make sure I am clear.  PERSON is the main table that holds everyone, both patients and parents.  Each PERSON has only one entry.  PATIENT is a subset of the data in PERSON.  RELATIONSHIP is a one-to-many in that a PERSON in RELATIONSHIP may appear multiple times.  Am I following?  Would it make sense to forego the PATIENT table and use a flag IsPatient?

Comment: I expected that `PATIENT` records would have lots of extra information that generic `PERSON` records do not, medical records, billing information, etc.  Keeping `PATIENT` separate from `PERSON` would allow you to separate out those concerns and business logic,  point records in future child tables such as medical history or payment history to a `PATIENT` to enforce consistency, etc.  If however the only differences between a patient and a non-patient is the simple fact they one is a patient and one isn't, then just adding an `IsPatient` flag would be the better approach.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  This seems to be working so far.  Will post some results as my testing proceeds.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach to the problem.

tbl_person, columns:

- id
- first_name
- last_name
- birth_date
- gender
- contact info
- other personal info

tbl_patient, columns:

- id
- tbl_person_id
- "other columns related to the patient like reason, symptoms, diagnosis, etc"

tbl_patient_has_guardian(one-to-many), columns:

- tbl_patient_id(primary key)
- tbl_person_id(primary key)
- patient_relationship_to_guardian_type

  - mother, father, etc

---

So when adding a new patient record, add the personal info to tbl_person, then reference tbl_person id to tbl_patient.

tbl_patient_has_guardian, one patient can have multiple guardians. The guardians has specific relationship type assigned to a patient, it could be a mother, father, etc.

Comment: This is the same as the earlier answer, except that it implies the type of relationship through the table name. The other answer where its called `relationship` is a more generic answer, and what I would do.